# "Schedule in advance" vs "schedule". Is "in advance" unnecessary?

Tags: meaning, differences, prepositional-phrases, redundancy

I'm not sure if it is correct to say "schedule in advance" or just "schedule".

Is it correct to say "schedule in advance" or should it just be "schedule" and "in advance" is unnecessary? What's the difference between the two?

Comment: You can hardly "schedule" something retrospectively (*after* it's happened), and it's entirely a matter of opinion whether *scheduling **in advance*** is an acceptable tautology or not.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: on the other hand, you can certainly try to schedule or reschedule an event containing lots of subevents (like a music festival, say) while it is happening. This can lead to complete chaos, which is why it is good to schedule things ***in advance.***

Comment: @Peter: I have absolutely no problem with *scheduling* or ***preparing** in advance*, and I don't really understand why so many people seem to think tautology / redundancy is somehow "undesirable" in language. As we know from examples like [If u cn rd ths ul gt th jk,](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2246) by any reasonable definition, ***most*** of the elements in any given utterance are "unnecessary".

Comment: Sometimes people say _to schedule_ meaning adding something to an "official" schedule like a Gantt chart for a project, or an addendum to a contract. With that sense, it might well be the case that an unplanned activity was done and then "scheduled" retroactively (so that the Gantt chart is complete or the contract is fully paid).

Comment: @PabloStraub Exactly, because the sense of *schedule something or someone for the future* is an extended meaning of the verb, which *basically* means *to enter into a schedule*, and a 'schedule' can be unconcerned or have nothing to do with the future: e.g. a tax schedule or drug schedule.

Answer (score 3):

While "schedule in advance" would seem on the face of it to be redundant, it's a [frequently-used phrase](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=schedule+in+advance&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cschedule%20in%20advance%3B%2Cc0) and is meaningful in the sense of setting the schedule or obtaining the reservations or whatever some significant period of time in advance (days/weeks/months) vs waiting until the last minute.

Answer (score 3):

**to schedule** means *to enter in a schedule or list* (OED). This corresponds to the noun *schedule*, meaning *any tabular or classified statement<sup>1</sup>*.

These can range from Train Schedules to Tax Schedules<sup>2</sup>. They do not have to deal with future events. For example, the  [Prime Minister’s schedule of taxable sources of income and gains](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/prime-ministers-schedule-of-taxable-sources-of-income-and-gains) *goes 'back 6 years'*.

Another  specific usage  of the verb is given in the  OED as a "draft addition"  (January 2010) meaning *To assign (a drug) to one of five classifications which place legal restrictions on availability and use*.

An **extended meaning** of the verb is *to place (something) on a programme of future events* (OED).

So, the verb *to schedule* does not necessarily imply or even involve the future, any more than the noun means or implies the future.

If I want to schedule Friday's events, I can  do that in advance or afterwards. For example, on Saturday I can  sit down and *schedule* everything I did the day before. I can, if I want,  do this on a *schedule* which can be  'a blank form to be filled up by the insertion of particulars under the several headings' (OED).

So, you can say *schedule* or, for clarity or emphasis, *schedule in advance*. Depending on context, *schedule* might be all you need to say, such as when you want to *schedule a (future) dentist's appointment*. Indeed your dentist may be able to schedule you on a walk-in basis or he may prefer to *schedule you (or an appointment for you)  in advance*.

Since you haven't given any context for your question, that's as specific as I'd like to be.

---

<sup>1</sup> *classified* here does not mean *secret* but *arranged according to classification.*

<sup>2</sup> "With reference to the British Income Tax, ‘Schedule A,’ ‘Schedule B,’ etc., are the official names for the forms of return applicable severally to the various classes into which sources of taxable income are divided"  (OED). Tax Schedules are also used by the US Department of Internal Revenue.

OED = *Oxford English Dictionary*

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference, but it is subtle.

The word *schedule* (as a verb) means you are planning something that hasn't occurred yet:

> to appoint, assign, or designate for a fixed time
>   - M-W

The definition does not explicitly state if the verb is for future or past tense, but the word itself implies future events; past events or future events that have been planned would be *scheduled*; for example:

> I have scheduled an appointment for you next week.

The phrase *schedule in advance* only makes sense if there was context around it. For example, if appointments were available for scheduling at 10 AM but you would like to schedule one and it was before 10 AM, but even then it is a bit of a stretch:

> I was wondering if I could schedule an appointment with you in advance?

However, in the *noun* form the phrase *schedule in advance* is perfectly fine:

> The agency has published its holiday schedule in advance of the long weekend.

Answer (score 0):

"Schedule" can be either a noun or a verb. You seem to be interested in the verb form. Therefore, while seemingly redundant, "schedule in advance" makes it clear what you mean, so I would recommend its use.

Scroll down to the verb form at the following site: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/schedule

Comment: It doesn't make sense to _schedule in the past_; The word itself implies events that haven't taken place.

Comment: Nor did I suggest it did. The question and all of the comments and answers (including mine) acknowledge the redundancy, but as FumbleFingers pointed out, redundancy isn't always bad.